# Android Studio - error: cannot find symbol class FirebaseAuth

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting these errors in Android:

```
error: cannot find symbol class FirebaseAuth
error: cannot find symbol variable FirebaseAuth
error: cannot find symbol class OnCompleteListener
error: cannot find symbol class AuthResult
```

My build.gradle in app:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
```

My build.gradle in project:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have added google maven repo at the project level -

```
allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        google() // Google's Maven repository
        // ...
    }
}
```

And, add this line at the bottom of app level gradle file -

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If you're still getting error then change the google service version to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

For more info, visit Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Comment: Implemented these changes but it's still telling me that it's unable to find FireBaseAuth.

Comment: As I don't have your full code, then please read the documentation carefully and try some online working examples. I hope you can catch your minor error then.

Comment: Ah, I did not know you had to "apply plugin" down the bottom.  I simply added id 'com.google.gms.google-services' INSIDE the "plugins{}" up the top.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

REMOVE THIS

```
rootProject.ext {
  set('FlutterFire', [
    FirebaseSDKVersion: '21.1.0'
  ])
}
```

in case you added it. works for me.